# Auto Complete is not working in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

If we give exact match or only one character its working fine, but if we give 2 or 3 characters `auto complete` is not working. For example if we give `T` or `Test` its working, but if i give `Tes` its not working.

My data looks like this

```
PUT /test/test/1
{
    "id": "1",
    "input": "Test",
    "output": ["Testing", "Testing"]
}

PUT /test/test/2
{
    "id": "2",
    "input": "Test two",
    "output":["Testing", "Testing"]
}
```

My elastic query is

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "tes"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting result with 'T'? are you using any custom analyzers? Is there any reason to query `_all` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a wildcard I believe:

```
GET /test/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "tes*"
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to use `"query": "input:tes*"` to autocomplete only one specific field.